# "you have ordered" vs "you ordered"

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, phrase-choice

Why does the author prefer to use present perfect in this case?

> I have included all the records you **have ordered**

Why not *ordered* as the two orders were made quite a long time ago (6 months and 8 months for the first one) and belong to the past

Is it because the seller thinks there will be more orders in the future or is it to emphasize the orders?

Comment: Useful formatting edits!

Comment: This needs context, what was said earlier? Please supply the source.

Comment: the context is that I made two orders a long time ago and have not received them and have forgotten I made them when today I have received this email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific context, I struggle to see any difference at all between the two formulations. Possibly, but only just, "have ordered" suggests that the order was given relatively recently, and you state that it was not, but even then the transaction is current, and therefore recent, as far as the supplier is concerned. So in the supplier's mind "have ordered" is correct in every way.

If the supplier wished to write to you about an order that was in the past both for you and for the supplier (" I am writing to you about the books you ordered three years ago, for which you have not yet paid...") then the single word "ordered" would be used.